# Including users in insert link internal link search in Gutenberg

Tags: users, block-editor, links

When I select text and insert a link in WordPress admin using Gutenberg, WordPress searches for internal pages based on the link text. It returns posts, custom posts etc., but not users.

I found some information about how to show users’ meta data in the REST API (which I think is what needs to happen?):

https://www.forumming.com/question/19309/wordpress-rest-api-and-user-meta-data

and tried adding this in functions.php:

`register_meta( ‘user’, ‘first_name’, [ ‘show_in_rest’ => true ] );`

But no success.

Is it possible to include users in the search?

Thank you for any pointers!

Regards
Mike